# How to randomly pick integer interval/range

Tags: python, random

I have a list 0-9: [0,1,2,3,…,9]
I want randomly output 2 vector with given span and consecutive numbers, drawn without replacement.
If span=3
output may be
([2,3,4], [7,8,9])
or
([3,4,5], [6,7,8])

two vectors can not overlap.
Any advice?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you not need repetations?

Comment: just one time. I want to permute ids. so I need to decide which two block are chosen to exchange.

Comment: Got you, then pick out the without replacement code from the answer I have given below. Hope it helps @zuujhyt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
lst = list(range(0,10))
import random

span = 3
def get_random(lst, span):
    starting_first = random.sample(lst[:-span*2+1], 1)[0]
    first_return = [starting_first, starting_first+1, starting_first+2]
    second_start = random.sample(lst[lst.index(first_return[-1]):-span+1],1)[0]
    second_return = [second_start, second_start+1, second_start+2]
    return (first_return, second_return)
```

This can take any lst in ascending order. Not just [0-9]. If you require only from [0,9], we can make a simpler code too. Do let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code. But in my case is simpler I think. The ids in the vectors need to be continuous.

Comment: Oh okay, got you, will update the code to match your need then.

Comment: @zuujhyt just edited the answer, please check.